# PID in top different from the $$ one?

Tags: process

I have been always running my following job.

```
#!/bin/sh

NO_START=1
STEP_SIZE=1
NO_END=100

DATE_STR=$(date +%m%d_%H%M%S)
RUN_DIR=./$DATE_STR

mkdir $RUN_DIR

echo PID = $$. See $RUN_DIR/$$.log for outputs and errors.
log_file=$RUN_DIR/$$.log; exec > $log_file 2>&1; date

for i in `seq $NO_START $STEP_SIZE $NO_END`
do
    ./c/anExternalCProgram $RUN_DIR
done
```

I notice today that the PID echoed is different from the one shown in `top`. Why is it so?

Comment: How do you view this in top? This Bourn shell script exits so quickly it never shows up in top, on 10+ tries

Comment: This, as said in the question, is only the start of the script. After this, I do have some operations that take days, allowing me to view it in `top`.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the script, so we can analyse or maybe reproduce. My guess is you are seeing some subshell in top

Comment: @Anthon It would be rather tedious for you to reproduce this, since it involves another C program. But I have updated the question with the overall flow.

Comment: Are you sure the top entry for `sh` of the program and not the one of the subshell started for the backquoted `seq` command?

Comment: @Anthon In `top`, the process name is indeed `anExternalCProgram `. The reason why it bothers me is that I have killed the script by its PID, but I still see `anExternalCProgram` running.

Comment: That the C program doesn't get killed might be because it detaches itself from its parent or ignores some signals.

Comment: @Anthon If that is the case, how may I stop them? Kill them by the PID shown in top? But I have many jobs, so it is easy to mis-kill others...

Comment: `pkill anExternalCProgram` should just get this C program. Optionally add `--signal ..` Or do you have many of those running simultaneously? This is turning into a new question, please post that as a separate one, if you need more assistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug this, in `top` select <kbd>f</kbd>for fields and switch on `PPID` by moving the cursor there and pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>. You might need to deselect one of the other fields (`VIRT`) so you can actually see this Parent Process ID.

Using the `PPID` you should be able to tell which program invoked that shell, it is probably your program's PID, and you are actually looking at a subshell in `top`.